# How to show multiple images in VBA userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to write a code in VBA and use a userform to show multiple images of the same item and rank them which one would be the best. I need the number, 1 being the best one to 3 being the last pick to be stored in a cell next to the image. I will put screenshots of my data as well as the userform I made. Below is the code I wrote but somehow not showing any images at all.
Thank you.

[image: data]

[image: userform]

```
Dim ImageName As String
Dim CopyImage As String
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox3_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox5_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox8_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Last Row"
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call GetImage
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(6349, 11).Select
    
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Saved"
        ActiveCell.Offset(6349, 11).Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call GetImage
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()

    If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Or ActiveCell.Row = 1 Or ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        Cells(6349, 10).Select
    End If
    
    Call GetImage
    
    cmdBack.Enabled = True
    cmdNext.Enabled = True

End Sub
Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

   ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Last Row"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call GetImage
    End If
    
End Sub
Private Sub RankButton_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image1_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image2_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image3_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image4_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image5_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image6_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image7_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub Image8_Click()

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    cmdBack.Enabled = False
    cmdNext.Enabled = False
    'cmdSave.Enabled = False
 
End Sub
Private Sub GetImage()

    Dim PhotoNames As String, fPath As String, iFile As String
    Dim i As Integer
        fPath = "D:\transfer\2021-12-13_image_ranking\dayco\2021-11-15_merged_dayco\"
    Dim CurrentPartNumber As String
    Dim CurrentImageIndex As Integer
        
        CurrentImageIndex = 1

        CurrentPartNumber = ActiveCell.Value
        
    Sheets("IMAGE").Select
    
    Dim CurrentCellValue As String
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
        CurrentRow = 6349
        CurrentCellValue = Cells(CurrentRow, 10)
        
    While Not (CurrentCellValue = "")
    
        If CurrentCellValue = CurrentPartNumber Then
        If Not Dir(fPath & Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Value) = "" Then
                
        Me.Controls("Image" & CurrentImageIndex).Picture = LoadPicture(fPath & Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Value)
        CurrentImageIndex = CurrentImageIndex + 1
        
        End If
        End If
                
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        CurrentCellValue = Cells(CurrentRow, 1)
             
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the row and column numbers of the table shown in the first image ?

Comment: Row 3, Column A

Comment: What is in `Cells(6349, 10)` ? `LoadPicture(fPath & Cells(CurrentRow, 10).Value` is using column J.